# ICS without confirmation email

Tags: icalendar

Some mail/calendar clients send automatic confirmation email after an ICS invitation has been accepted or rejected. Is it somehow possible to deactivate this? The event is mandatory and not optional.

In my case the ICS file is just a confirmation of an appointment booked before.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:internalID
ORGANIZER;CN="name":MAILTO:info@test.de
LOCATION:Location
SUMMARY:Some appointment
DESCRIPTION:Appointment booked
CLASS:PRIVATE
[..]
END:VEVENT
```

Obviously it would be possible to remove the mail field, but I would like to keep the mail information in the invitation.

Comment: Seems to depend on the client, for example http://superuser.com/questions/33581/how-to-prevent-ical-from-sending-emails